# Qt: model/view concept with text browser

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I am writing an application in Qt with C++. In this application I have to display an amount of data in a text box.

Is there a way to use QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit with the model/view concept in Qt? I only found list, tree, or table View classes with mvc functionality.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit with the model/view concept in Qt?

No.

For using model/view concept you need use already existed classes which inherit [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html) (such as: `QColumnView`, `QHeaderView`, `QListView`, `QTableView` and `QTreeView`) or inherit your custom class.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Qt documentation. There are the options you have: 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html

## Models

> `QAbstractItemModel` provides an interface to data that is flexible
>   enough to handle views that represent data in the form of tables,
>   lists, and trees. However, when implementing new models for list and
>   table-like data structures, the `QAbstractListModel` and
>   `QAbstractTableModel` classes are better starting points because they
>   provide appropriate default implementations of common functions.

## Views

> `QListView` displays a list of items, `QTableView` displays data from
>   a model in a table, and `QTreeView` shows model items of data in a
>   hierarchical list. Each of these classes is based on the
>   `QAbstractItemView` abstract base class.

## Controller

> `QAbstractItemDelegate` is the abstract base class for delegates in
>   the model/view framework.